# Google Chart - Incorrect Data Array Format in PHP

Tags: php, google-visualization

I'm trying to display a monthly sales graph but unable to format data array for google chart function. Here's what I have:

STEP 1: Array formed from resultset:

```
Array ( [Jan] => 0 [Feb] => 0 [Mar] => 0 [Apr] => 0 [May] => 0 [Jun] => 0 [Jul] => 0 [Aug] => 0 [Sep] => 0 [Oct] => 60.123 [Nov] => 0 [Dec] => 0 )
```

STEP 2: JSON encode:

```
$chartdata = json_encode($data);
```

STEP 3: Load Google Chart Function:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable($chartdata, true);
```

But it doesn't display any chart. Any suggestions?

Google API: https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/datatables_dataviews

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't work because the `arrayToDataTable` method does not accept an object in that format.  This should work:

In PHP:

```
$data = array (
    array('Month', 'Sales'),
    array('Jan', 0),
    array('Feb', 0),
    array('Mar', 0),
    array('Apr', 0),
    array('May', 0),
    array('Jun', 0),
    array('Jul', 0),
    array('Aug', 0),
    array('Sep', 0),
    array('Oct', 60.123),
    array('Nov', 0),
    array('Dec', 0)
);
$chartdata = json_encode($data);
```

In javascript:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<?php echo $chartdata; ?>);
```